# View media with group permissions

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, group

I have a file media type and these files will be private files, with different access levels (1, 2 etc).

What I need

1. View page only for registered users, if the user has granted access level 1, the user can access/view all files from level 1,
2. if the user has granted level 2, it is possible to access/view all files from level 2

and so on, for each level.

Same user can have multiple levels.

What I tried - Taxonomy plus view

1. Create a taxonomy term, with all levels (1, 2 etc)
2. Added a taxonomy field on media called "Access Level", where on each media file I set the level
3. Added a taxonomy field on user calles "File Access Level" where on each user I set the level (users can have multiple levels)
4. Create a view of media and try to match media field with user field, without success (used relationship to be able to add user field, but relationship user is always on authored context and I don't want that)

What I tried - Group module plus view

1. Create a group for each level (1, 2 etc), and set role to individual, so I can choose which user will be access
2. Added the users that I want to each level
3. Created a "Reference - other" field in media file, choose "Group"
4. On each media file I set the Group level that I need
5. Created a view of media and set Group permission, no matter what option I choose, I always get access denied, event with admin account

Any idea to address this result?

Thanks in advance :)